# Remove a property from Json in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a Json string and I want to remove some properties.

This is my string and I want to remove `data`'s values:

```
"dev1": {
    "serial": 123,
    "channels": {
      "1": {
        "humidity": {
          "parameters": {},
          "data": [
            [
              **-3.0,
              -4.0**
            ]
          ]
        },
        "temprature": {
          "parameters": {},
          "data": [
            [
              **-3.0,
              -4.0**
            ]
          ],
          "weHadAlarmed": false
        },
        "channelName": "CH1"
      },
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the rest of your json might look like, but using Newtonsoft.Json (Json.net), something like this would do it

```
    var json = "{ \"serial\": 123, \"channels\": { \"1\": { \"humidity\": { \"parameters\": {}, \"data\": [ [ -3.0, -4.0 ] ] }, \"temprature\": { \"parameters\": {}, \"data\": [ [ -3.0, -4.0 ] ], \"weHadAlarmed\": false }, \"channelName\": \"CH1\" } } }";

    var job = JObject.Parse(json);
    job.SelectToken("channels").SelectToken("1").Values().ToList().ForEach(chan =>
    {
        if(chan.GetType() == typeof(JObject) && chan["data"] != null)
        {
            // empty array
            chan["data"] = new JArray();
            // or set it to null
            //chan["data"] = null;
        }               
    });

    string newJsonStringWouldBe = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(job);
```